# Trouble installing Helios - Java error

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the same error other people get:
Java was started but returned error code=13

I've looked in many places and I understand the nature of the error. It's a combination of getting the PATH right and getting the right JRE. So far so good.

Trouble is, I think I've done that. My path has 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin
in it, and my eclipse.ini has these lines just above -vmargs:
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe

I do indeed have JRE6 and it's in that location and I did download it from Oracle, verified as current by that site.

I'm running Windows7 64-bit. I think JRE6 got installed in the x86 folder because that's where the older JREs are located. Out of frustration I tried pointing to the most recent of those (jre1.6.0_22) but of course that did no good either.

I've read numerous how-to articles and they all say more or less the same thing. Get the path right, make sure you have a current JRE, and add those lines to the ini file. Check, check and check.

I'd sure appreciate it if someone could tell me what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error when you attempt to run a 64bit Eclipse on a 32bit JVM. Align the one and other. I'd uninstall the 32bit JRE/JDK by control panel > add/remove programs and then reinstall a 64bit one from http://java.com. It will automatically recognize the platform and install the right one. Otherwise download it manually from [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Be careful that you choose the right platform version.

Oh, I'd also undo the changes you made in `eclipse.ini`. Keep them untouched as long as you don't *understand* what the error means and what those lines do.

Comment: All apps contained in "Program Files (x86)" are 32-bit. The actual 64-bit JVM will install under regular "Program Files" location, regardless of where previous JVMs are installed. You can also check 32-bit/64-bit variety by running "java -version" on the given JVM.

Comment: I'd avoid uninstalling 32-bit JRE as that will likely break Java support in your web browser. While 64-bit browsers are available, most people still use 32-bit variety because most plugins aren't yet offered as 64-bit.

Comment: I understand. I'll give it another look, but I thought I did install the 64-bit version and was surprised to find it did not go in Program Files. Maybe I chose the wrong option. I'll give it another look.

In the meantime, out of frustration (I've had trouble with Eclipse installs on other computers) I installed NetBeans, which simply worked right out of the box. So at least I have an IDE. But thank you very much for the advice.